# How to convert list of strings in .txt file into a dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a list of values that I am reading from a .txt file and am trying to convert that into a dataframe in R:

.txt data:

```
l_arr(0, 1, 1) = 0;
l_dep(0, 1, 1) = 7.36639;
r_arr(0, 1, 1) = 0;
r_dep(0, 1, 1) = 0;
l_arr(0, 1, 2) = 51.9099;
l_dep(0, 1, 2) = 51.9099;
r_arr(0, 1, 2) = 0.4;
r_dep(0, 1, 2) = 0.4;
```

Corresponding dataframe in R:

[image: corresponding dataframe in R:]

I currently have this:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 5))
x <- c("Type", "Angle", "Row", "Boundary", "Timestamp")
colnames(df) <- x

data<-read.csv("SWV_data.txt", header=TRUE, sep = ",")
data<-as.character(data)
temp<-(unlist(strsplit(data,"(")))
```

I am struggling with working with the text strings because as soon as I use as.character, the entire structure of the data in the .txt is lost

Comment: you need to provide sample data, not an image. You can use copy the .txt data,  paste it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try reading the text file using `readLines`, replace all the extra characters (`,()=;`) with empty space using `gsub`, split on space to get different columns. Use `type.convert` to convert columns into their respective types.

```
output <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(gsub("[,()=;]", " ", 
                        readLines("demo.txt")), "\\s+")))
output <- type.convert(output)
names(output) <- c("Type", "Angle", "Row", "Boundary", "TimeStam")

output
#   Type Angle Row Boundary TimeStam
#1 l_arr     0   1        1     0.00
#2 l_dep     0   1        1     7.37
#3 r_arr     0   1        1     0.00
#4 r_dep     0   1        1     0.00
#5 l_arr     0   1        2    51.91
#6 l_dep     0   1        2    51.91
#7 r_arr     0   1        2     0.40
#8 r_dep     0   1        2     0.40
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `readLines` then delete all the unnecesary characters:

```
nm <- c("Type", "Angle", "Row", "Boundary", "TimeStam")
read.table(text=sub('_',',',gsub('[^A-Z0-9.a-z_]',' ',readLines("a.txt"))),col.names = nm)
   Type Angle Row Boundary TimeStam
1 l,arr     0   1        1  0.00000
2 l,dep     0   1        1  7.36639
3 r,arr     0   1        1  0.00000
4 r,dep     0   1        1  0.00000
5 l,arr     0   1        2 51.90990
6 l,dep     0   1        2 51.90990
7 r,arr     0   1        2  0.40000
8 r,dep     0   1        2  0.40000
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create each column by regex matching, you can use `tidyr::extract` with capture groups to match the type of text that corresponds to each column. In this example, the file you start with is structured well for this, but it may not work well in other cases.

```
txt <- readLines("data.txt")
tidyr::extract(data.frame(txt), txt, 
               into = c("Type", "Angle", "Row", "Boundary", "TimeStam"),
               regex = "(^\\w+)\\((\\d+), (\\d+), (\\d+)\\) = ([\\d.]+);$")
```

Note that this wouldn't change each column from being strings; if you need to change that, a call such as `dplyr::mutate_at(vars(-Type), as.numeric)` would do that conversion quickly.